# Where can I find historical exchange rate data for BTC/USD?

Tags: raw-data, exchange-rate

I'm looking for historical exchange rate data for Bitcoins/USD beginning in 2010, but I haven't been successful. This is for academic research. I tried bitchart.org. I don't know how to access the MtGox API either.

Can you help me with a step-by-step procedure to download the data in CSV format (or any other format)? It would be awesome if you could just provide me with the actual data file.

Comment: I've used http://bitcoincharts.com/ in the past, though it seems to be down at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://www.coindesk.com/price
- http://www.investing.com/currencies/btc-usd-historical-data
- http://www.quandl.com/c/markets/bitcoin-data
- https://bitcoinchain.com/markets

Also, there was a [Bitcoin Time Series spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmcTCtjBoRWUdHJuUE1mUkFxa3A0eHBDQkxZLVVFZmc).  Scroll to the bottom to see the data sources.

Comment: Hey Stephen, the excel file you linked to appears not to be updated.Do you mind updating it to the latest history? thnx